# How to "reload" just one vhost file

Tags: apache-config

I have a question about apache configuration. Please help me! 
My server run multi virtual hosts (multi domains). But, every time I edit a vhost file, I have to restart apache, and, server have to reload all configuration files. That is expensive. Is there any way to "restart" or "reload" **just one** vhost configuration file? I googled but haven't found the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the answer is "No". I've been looking for this for a while, too.  Although, you say "restart apache", what command are you running? Are you using the apache `restart` or `reload` command? You should only have to use `reload`.